# JasperReport no encuentra subreporte con Java y MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, pdf, jasper-reports

Tengo un problema que no logro solventar.
Les explico, he creado un pequeño sistema que genera reportes, hasta aquí todo bien, el problema empezó cuando comencé a incluir subreportes.
Al estar trabajando todo en NetBeans corre sin problema, creo mi ejecutable .jar y hasta aquí todo bien, incluyo los reportes como debería y corren a la perfección, la cuestión es que este sistema necesito compartirlo por la red y al momento de pegarlo en mi carpeta compartida en la red, abre el sistema y se pueden hacer las consultas correspondientes a la base de datos y crear algunos reportes, he aquí el asunto. Me permite crear reportes que NO contengan subreportes, pero aquellos que tiene un subreporte, no los crea, se queda cargando, finaliza y no lo crea, ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Agradecería que me indicaran qué archivos necesitarían ver, gracias.

Comment: *Actualización* Ya le indiqué en el path la URL del subreporte y ni aún así parametros.put("SUBREPORTE_REG", "reportes\\comisionados.jasper");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

después de darle miles de vueltas encontré la solución, se las comparto.

El problema estaba al conectar el subreporte con el reporte maestro. Cometí el grave error de, cuando toca indicarle en dónde se encuentra el subreporte, hacerlo con un parámetro.

Entonces la solución fue sencillamente utilizar una ruta absoluta estática y ¡Listo! Asunto resuelto.

Tuve que echarme un clavado a investigar desde 0 la importación y navegando encontré una parte de este interesante post que dejo aquí:

***"También podemos ejegir si queremos guardar la ruta del subreporte (para que el reporte maestro sepa donde buscarlo) como un parámetro llamado $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}, o como una ruta absoluta estática. Lo mejor es elegir está ultima ya que modificaremos la ruta para que busque el subreporte en en el mismo directorio que el reporte maestro. Así si los movemos de un directorio a otro, solo tendremos que preocuparnos de llevarnos los dos juntos."***

Post completo [aquí.](https://www.javatutoriales.com/2009/04/creacion-de-reportes-con-jasperrepots-y_18.html)